# How to update RealityKit world position SIMD3 constantly?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to place an object at the world position using RealityKit, set with a timer that will clear all anchors and place new object in every 5 seconds.

The problem is no matter how I move my camera, the object is still placed at the same location in every 5 seconds.

How can I update the world position SIMD3 constantly?

This is my code here.

```
  @objc func updateTimer(){
        
        if secondsPassed < 1 {
            
            let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: SIMD3(x: 0, y: -0.25, z: -0.4))
        
            let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.04), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)])

            anchor.addChild(box)

            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
            
            secondsPassed += 1
            
            
        } else if secondsPassed < 5 {
            
            secondsPassed += 1
            
            
        } else {
            
            secondsPassed = 0
            
            arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use removeFromParent() function of ModelEntity() & use addChild() function of AnchorEntity() and make sure to import RealityKit.

Reference:
[Reference to the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741985/how-to-add-a-new-scene-to-an-existing-anchor-and-remove-the-previous-scene)